# Blender IK animation becomes inaccurate when exported

Tags: animation, .fbx, inverse-kinematics

Animating a robot with 8 bones, I chose to use IK animation with the iTaSC (SDLS) solver. In Blender everything works great, but when exporting the animation there are accuracy issues.

I made a video showcasing the problem <[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1VG1HDF11o)>. First you see the IK version (3 shots), then the imported FBX (2 shots, with a low framerate because now blender has too many keys).

Blender applies the IK, so each bone gets its own movement (and I'm thinking this 'cascades' an accumulating inaccuracy, resulting in visible movement of the tip of my robot.

Any ideas on how to improve on this result? Is there a way to get better accuracy?

Comment: If you've finalized the animation before export, is it possible that you could use the 'Bake Action' option to apply keyframes on every frame. That way there is no interpolation, and your animation is explicit.

Comment: I did in fact use that option (which is why after import the FPS is low since it has to process all those keyframes). It didn't help though.

Comment: It's a shame to have animation fail at this last stage though.. Everything else is working perfectly!